# Node.js dirty how do i get data from [Object object]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-dirty

How to i get the data from from `[Object object]`?

Here is an example of what i'm trying to do.

```
// Get data with dirty
var data = db.get('/htmltest')

// My test.db file
{"key":"foo","val":"barwhat?"}
{"key":"/htmltest","val":{"title":"Html Test","content":"<span>This is HTML</span>"}}


// the console.log gives me [Object Object]
// How do I get it to show the content of title (Html Test)
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/felixge/node-dirty), the `get` method returns the value for a given key. In that case you should be able to access the `title` property like so:

```
// Get data with dirty
var data = db.get('/htmltest')

// My test.db file
{"key":"foo","val":"barwhat?"}
{"key":"/htmltest","val":{"title":"Html Test","content":"<span>This is HTML</span>"}}


// the console.log gives me [Object Object]
// How do I get it to show the content of title (Html Test)
console.log(data.title);
```

Answer (score 3):

Another thing that you can do to help view your data for debugging is to use the `util` [inspect function](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_showhidden_depth_colors).

```
var util = require('util');
var data = db.get('/htmltest');

console.log(util.inspect(data));
```

Again, this is only useful for debugging and inspecting the contents of objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you certify that your `data` variable is a JSON object, you can also parse easily it and show all content in one row using `JSON.stringify(data);`